How to setup QR code scanner device (not webcam) in .NET
I have a QR code scanner device NETUM AT-A5 (USB) and the plan is to scan URLs with it, do some custom logic and then do HTTP request with the data read from QR code.
My plan was to run it as Windows service, hook to OnQrCodeRead (or similar) event, send http request, and continue listening with scanner.
It would be nice to have some basic methods such as GetScanner, DisposeScanner, OnQrCodeRead (event), and similar...
The problem I'm facing is how to connect to QR code scanner properly in .NET6. Should I be using some other .NET version? Is there any library that could make this easier? I've seen BarcodeScanner class from Microsoft but I'm unable to use it, is there any alternative?

The following may be of interest: Netum Barcode Scanner User Manuals and NetumScan User Manauals.  Look for the phrase USB COM or USB Serial. Scanning the appropriate code will configure the barcode scanner. Then one can use the SerialPort Class
